# Understanding what self is when calling super on child

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the code below.

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__class__.__name__)
    def handle(self):
        print("Beginning handle Base")
        self.template()
    def template(self):
        print("template of Base") 

class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
    def handle(self):
        print("Beginning handle Child")
        super(Child, self).handle()
    def template(self):
        print("template of Child")

parent = Base()
child = Child()
```

Here I would expect the following to print

```
'Base'
'Child'
```

So that is fine, except when I call this:

```
parent.handle()
child.handle()
```

I would expect:

```
"Beginning handle Base"
"template of Base"
"Beginning handle Child"
"Beginning handle Base"
"template of Base"
```

But instead I am getting

```
"Beginning handle Base"
"template of Base"
"Beginning handle Child"
"Beginning handle Base"
"template of Child"
```

Why is this happening? Isn't self.template() in the handle function of Base referring to the the template function of base? What is `super(Child, self).handle()` actually doing? To me it seems it's calling the handle of it's parent, but setting self to itself...

Comment: What is `ChildB` in `Child`'s `handle`?

Comment: That is supposed to be `Child`... have updated the question

Comment: When calling `child.handle()`, `self` is `child` throughout.  It is passed to `Base.handle` but it's still `child`, so when `self.template()` is called from `Base.handle`, it's `Child.template` that gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `super` isn't used explicitly, normal dynamic lookup occurs, and that always starts at the real class. `self.template()` calls in `Base` call the `template` function with normal dynamic dispatch, and get `Child`'s `template`, not `Base`s; the assumption being that if `Child` overrode `template`, it has a behavior that is better for it than the one `Base` provides. If it didn't override, it would get `Base`'s version.

Think of `super` as tossing up the chain only for calls made directly on `super` results; otherwise, it's not involved, and normal lookup occurs (`Base` calling `template` is just like anyone else calling `template`, not different at all). The `self` passed as a result of the `Base` call is no different.

If for some reason `Base` wanted to stymie dynamic lookup (so children couldn't change the method without going to a lot of trouble) it could do either:

```
def handle(self):
    print("Beginning handle Base")
    Base.template(self)
```

explicitly specifying the class, or change `template` to `__template` to trigger `class` private access (seamless name mangling), e.g.

```
def handle(self):
    print("Beginning handle Base")
    self.__template()
def __template(self):
    print("template of Base")
```

and even if `Child` made its own `__template`, that `__template` would be private to the `Child`, and would not be invoked if `Base` methods used it (but then, no one outside of `Child` could call it without trouble either).

Answer (score 4):

[Python 2 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

> `super(type[, object-or-type])`
>   Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or
>   sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods
>   that have been overridden in a class. The search order is same as that
>   used by getattr() except that the type itself is skipped.

So in your case **super(Child, self).handle()** doing next:

Calling `handle` method of parent of `Child`(which is `Base`) and passing `Child` instance as `self` to that method.

Take a look what happens in you code snippet:

```
parent.handle()
// Calling handle of parent, nothing special. 
// "Beginning handle Base"
//  "template of Base"
child.handle()
// Calling handle of child: "Beginning handle of Child" - logged
// handle method of child calls handle method of parent: "Beginning handle Base" - logged
// handle method of Base calls  template method of self which is template method of Child as self passed to super as second parameter.: "template of Child" - logged
```

So that's normal behaviour for code snippet above.